I can't get data from props
I populate data prop from App.js file and send it to CarDetails page.
App.js (I console data here and it shows me an array of objects)
const [data, setData] = useState<CarType[]>([])
     <Route exact path="/carDetails/:id">
        <CarDetails data={data} />
     </Route>

In CarDetails.js it's undefined after FIND () method. as a prop it's showing an array of objects
const [item, setItem] = useState<CarType>({} as CarType)

  const { id } = useParams<{ id: string }>()
  useEffect(() => {
    const found = data.find((item) => item.id === id)
    if (found) {
      setItem(found)
    }
  
  }, [data, id])

so when I console log const found it's undefined.

Can you show more of your code? Where is your console.log?
